# JQuery: How to set datepicker starting date in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-range, daterangepicker

I am trying to set the start and end date of a date range of a `datepicker()`, where the starting date of the range is 7 days in the past and the ending date is yesterday.

Currently I have it working so that the starting date of the range is 7 days in the past however I don't know how to set the ending date to yesterday.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work as I expect it to:

```
var mindate = new Date();
    mindate.setDate(mindate.getDate() - 7);
    $('#date').datepicker({
        language: 'en',
            range : true,
            minDate : mindate,
            maxDate : new Date() - 1,   //I guess the problem is here
            multipleDates: true,
            multipleDatesSeparator: " - "
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to compute a `maxdate` using the same technquie as you have used to compute `mindate` and then apply that max date value to the `maxData` parameter of the `datepicker()` instance:

```
var mindate = new Date();
mindate.setDate(mindate.getDate() - 7);

/* Compute max date of "yesterday" using same method as 
min date */
var maxdate = new Date();
maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate() - 1);

$('#date').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    range : true,
    minDate : mindate,
    maxDate : maxdate, /* Apply max date to date picker */
    multipleDates: true,
    multipleDatesSeparator: " - "
});
```

The `datepicker()` plugin also allows you to specify `minDate` and `maxDate` via [the number of days relative to today's date](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate). That means you can achieve the same result as shown above without needing to calculate `mindate` and `maxdate` by specifying `minDate` and `maxDate` as shown:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    range : true,
    minDate : -7, /* 7 days ago */
    maxDate : -1, /* Yesterday */
    multipleDates: true,
    multipleDatesSeparator: " - "
});
```

Answer (score 1):

minDate and maxDate can the amount of days from today.

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

So all you need to do is

```
minDate: -1,
maxDate: -7,
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you already have a `<input type="date">` so you don't need any kind of jQuery.

Unless you need support for legacy browsers I can only recommend using HTML5 over jquery.

HTML

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
```

Vanilla JS

```js
function getHtmlDateString(date) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
  } 
  if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
  } 

  return yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
}

var min = new Date();
min.setDate(min.getDate()-7);
document.getElementById("date").setAttribute("min", getHtmlDateString(min));
var max = new Date();
max.setDate(max.getDate()-1);
document.getElementById("date").setAttribute("max", getHtmlDateString(max));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hmqe4sb6/